# how add icon for RibbonApplicationMenu?

Tags: java

I have an application in Java and I want it to have a RibbonApplicationMenu with icon.

I already have the RibbonApplicationMenu but with no icon. I was wondering if it is possible to add an Icon to the RibbonApplicationMenu?

And also I found the following code, everytime I used the code below, it gives me exception

public static ResizableIcon getResizableIconFromResource(String resource) {

```
    return ImageWrapperResizableIcon.getIcon(MainFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource), new Dimension(48, 48));
}
```

Exception:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.common.icon.ImageWrapperResizableIcon.getIcon(ImageWrapperResizableIcon.java:71)
        at com.scamex.app.MainFrame.getResizableIconFromResource(MainFrame.java:187)
        at com.scamex.app.MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:86)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: One of your object is null, I would recommend you print each one of them to see which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
JCommandButton button1 = new JCommandButton("Square", getResizableIconFromResource("48px-Crystal_Clear_action_bookmark.png"));

public static ResizableIcon getResizableIconFromResource(String resource)
{   
  System.out.println("Resources:"+resource);
  return   ImageWrapperResizableIcon.getIcon(MainFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/"+resource), new Dimension(48, 48));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to wrong image path, that what gives you NULL. Try with the correct image path and it will work.